# Can you have a function be a const and also return a const C++

Tags: c++, class

For example if the member function of a class is:

```
const QStringList& getList() const
```

Returning a whole list is potentially an expensive operation but I also don't want the function to be able to change the private member variables of the class. I'm curious on this one.

Comment: where is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you have a function be a const and also return a const C++

Yes. A member function can simultaneously be const, and return a reference to const. In fact, this is quite typical when returning references to member variables.